# MySQL INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Cause ID Not In Sequential

Tags: mysql

I created a table using this SQL :

```
CREATE TABLE import_xlsx (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
date DATETIME,
pair VARCHAR(10),
action VARCHAR(5),
volume DECIMAL(20,8),
order_price DECIMAL(20,8),
trading_price DECIMAL(20,8),
status VARCHAR(20),
CONSTRAINT table_unique UNIQUE (date, pair, action));
```

and I have this `INSERT` :

```
INSERT INTO binance_xlsx (date, pair, action, volume, order_price, trading_price, status)
VALUES('2018-05-14 13:58:54', 'ETHUSDT', 'SELL', '0.1', '725.0', '724.95', 'Filled') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
status = VALUES(status);
```

I tried to insert duplicate rows on purpose, the number ID is auto-incremented. but number of rows still 1. shouldn't be only auto-incremented if new row inserted?

Here's the result :

```
+----+---------------------+---------+--------+------------+--------------+---------------+--------+
| id | date                | pair    | action | volume     | order_price  | trading_price | status |
+----+---------------------+---------+--------+------------+--------------+---------------+--------+
|  1 | 2018-05-14 13:58:53 | ETHUSDT | BUY    | 0.09889000 | 725.00000000 |  724.95000000 | Filled |
| 11 | 2018-05-14 13:58:53 | ETHUSDT | SELL   | 0.10000000 | 725.00000000 |  724.95000000 | Filled |
| 13 | 2018-05-14 13:58:54 | ETHUSDT | SELL   | 0.10000000 | 725.00000000 |  724.95000000 | Filled |
+----+---------------------+---------+--------+------------+--------------+---------------+--------+
```

how to keep the `id` auto-incremented in sequential order?

Comment: Those are _sequential_, it is just auto_increment does not guarantee they will be _continuous_. Attempts to ensure continuity on auto_increment are rarely worth the trouble. (Auto-increment values are reserved before the insert is completed to avoid parallelism-related issues.)

Comment: I mean, why `UPDATE` ON DUPLICATE KEY cause id auto-incremented? while there's new row created...

Comment: Check [Bug #61962 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' bug incrementing ID (auto increment field) on Updates](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61962) and [15.8.1.5 AUTO_INCREMENT Handling in InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html).

Answer (score 1):

That is just because your Primary Key it´s the auto incremented column, so when you try to insert, you never get a duplicate key and inserts a new row. This is your creation statement for the `id` column:

```
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

You should change it and make your **Primary Key**  your `(date, pair, action)` values so it will work